# Linking layers/groups

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I have a layer that I've duplicated (and will always be the same as the first layer), how can I make it so that if I change the first layer, it would automatically change the duplicated layer as well (basically, linking them so they act as one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Convert to Smart Object"** 
Right click on original layer, convert it to smart object. 
Duplicate it.

Happy Photoshopping!